# How to find $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(x + 1)^{\frac{1}{x}} - e}{x} $

Tags: calculus, limits

Let
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{(x + 1)^{\frac{1}{x}} - e}{x} = ? $$

How would you calculate it's limit? I thought using l'hopital rule, but it then becomes something nasty, as the differentiate of $(x + 1)^{\frac{1}{x}}$ isn't simple.

Comment: related : [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634749/finding-displaystyle-lim-x-to-inftyx-big1-tfrac1xx-mathrme-big)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @zhw already described, an efficient way to approach this is to use asymptotic analysis.  So, here we will use instead the "brute force" approach via L'Hospital's Rule.  To that end, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(x+1)^{1/x}-e}{x}&=\lim_{x\to 0}(x+1)^{1/x}\left(\frac{x-(x+1)\log(x+1)}{x^2(x+1)}\right)\\\\
&=e\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x-(x+1)\log(x+1)}{x^2(x+1)}\right)\\\\
&=e\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{-\log(x+1)}{3x^2+2x}\right)\\\\
&=e\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{-\frac{1}{x+1}}{6x+2}\right)\\\\
&=-e/2
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $(1+x)^{1/x} = e^{(\ln(1+x))/x}.$ Use $\ln (1+h) = h-h^2/2 +O(h^3), e^h = 1 +h+O(h^2)$ for small $h.$

Comment: This is the way to go here - the way that I would approach it naturally.  Inasmuch as you had already posted this, I tackled the problem "brute force" using L'Hospital's Rule, which shows the efficiency of asymptotics over The Old Hospital. +1

Answer (score 0):

With *Taylor's expansion at order* $\mathit 1$:
$$(1+x)^{\tfrac1x}=\mathrm e^\tfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=\mathrm e^{1-\tfrac{x}2+o(x)}=\mathrm e\Bigl(1-\frac x 2+o(x)\Bigr)$$
whence 
$$\frac{(1+x)^{\tfrac1x}-\mathrm e}x=\mathrm e\Bigl(-\frac12+o(1)\Bigr)\to-\frac{\mathrm e}2.$$

Comment: That's what I wrote on paper, but could not  retrieve where the $-$  sign came from :o(

Comment: The sign error is due to the incorrect expansion of the $\log(1+x)$ which is $$\log(1+x)=x-\frac12x^2+O(x^3)$$.  But how is this different from the approach by @zhw?

Comment: Found it finally! Corrected the answer. Thank you for pointing the error.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Dr MV: Thank  you. You were posting while I was correcting :o) People are really fast these days!

Comment: Usually faster than I ... ;-))

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it is "nasty" to differentiate $f(x)=(1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$. We have:

$$ f'(x) = f(x)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\log(f(x)) = (1+x)^{\frac{1}{x}}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x} $$
and since in a neighbourhood of the origin $\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$ we have:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+} f'(x) = e\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right).$$